# How to track a subdomain in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a domain say `in.mysite.com` . How do i track this website using Google Analytics?

I have a google analytics code but it shows my domain as: mysite.com

Answer (score 0):

Create a new profile that includes only traffic to domain `in.mysite.com`.

[image]